# How do you calculate the amount of parameters needed to be estimated?

Tags: data-mining, graphical-model, predictor

I don't quite understand this.

A question was, pretend we have 4 predictors and all of them are binary - for the Naive Bayes method, how many parameters are there to estimate in the training step? The answer was 2*4.

Then, another question was, if we draw an edge between predictors 1 and 2 to create a graphical model, how many parameters do we need to estimate in the training step? The answer was 1+1(2)+(2*7)=11.

Finally how about if all of the predictors have edges in between? The answer was 1+2(15)=31.

I don't get how these equations are being constructed. Could someone explain please?

Comment: how many groups are you trying to classify the data into?  is that given? (I'm guessing here it's 2).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, here it's 2. @EricPeterson

Answer (score 1):

Ok, then for the first question, 2 * 4. Let's assume that the predictors are yes/no and the groups to be classified in are Big and Small. The parameters of the Naive Bayes model are:

$P(Big|Y_1 or N_1),P(Big|Y_2 or N_2),P(Big|Y_3 or N_3),P(Big|Y_4 or N_4)$
and

$P(Small|Y_1 or N_1),P(Small|Y_2 or N_2),P(Small|Y_3 or N_3),P(Small|Y_4 or N_4)$

8 total parameters.

Sorry, I missed these were binary predictors.  Everything is either yes or no.

Comment: Um, like I commented on your last answer. Thank you! That makes sense, but how do I alter it when an "edge" is added? If the relation between the first and second predictors is added, wouldn't it add 2 parameters? P(Big|Y1 or N1, Y2 or N2) and P(Small|Y1 or N1, Y2 or N2)

Comment: Oops the above one was for you, @EricPeterson

Comment: I would think that `P(big | y1 or n1)` is equal to `1 - P(small | y1 or n1)`, how can these be multiple parameters?